# How to find nearest users from Latitude and Longitude

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I want to query nearby users, but I am getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1582 Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'radians' (SQL: select *, ( 6367 * acos( cos( radians() ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians() ) + sin( radians() ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance from `users` having `distance` < 25 order by `distance` asc)

My Query:

```
 $user = User::where('id' , Auth()->user()->id)->first();
    $latitude = $user->lat;
    $longitude = $user->long;

    $suggestions = User::select(DB::raw('*, ( 6367 * acos( cos( radians('.$latitude.') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians('.$longitude.') ) + sin( radians('.$latitude.') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance'))
                ->having('distance', '<', 25)
                ->orderBy('distance')
                ->get();
```

Comment: It seems like radians is getting the wrong number of arguments. Could you check that $latitude, $longitude, latitude and longitude are of the expected values? i.e. not empty or mulitple values for example?